# Volatile keyword error in java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am trying to write a simple code to understand **volatile** keyword in java.

The idea is to increment the value of *count* field of Runner class using two threads. Helper class implements Runnable where run method increments the *count* which both *static* and *volatile*.

```
        class Helper implements Runnable{

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0; i<100000;i++){         
                    Runner.count+=1;
                }

            }
        }


        public class Runner {

            public static volatile long count=0; // to be incremented

            public static void main(String[] args){

                Thread t1 = new Thread( new Helper()); 
                Thread t2 = new Thread( new Helper());

                t1.start();
                t2.start();

                try {
                    t1.join();
                    t2.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Count= "+count); // output expected to be 200000
            }

        }
```

> The expected output for every run is *Count= 200000* , but sometimes i get a different number.
>   Please help me understand how is that possible

Comment: Volatile provides visibility, but not atomicity (which is what a compound operation such as variable increment requires).

Answer (score 4):

The effect of the volatile keyword is approximately that each individual read or write operation on that variable is atomic.

Notably, however, an operation that requires more than one read/write -- such as i++, which is equivalent to i = i + 1, which does one read and one write -- is not atomic, since another thread may write to i between the read and the write.

Answer (score 3):

```
Runner.count+=1;
```

means:

```
Runner.count = Runner.count + 1;
```

or, in other words:

1. Get the value of `Runner.count`.
2. Add 1 to this value.
3. Store the new value in `Runner.count`.

Thread A and B could both get the value of `Runner.count` (so they both get 1), and then both add 1 to it at the same time (so they both get 2), and then both store it back at the same time (so the new value is 2) - and now the value went from 1 to 2, and not 1 to 3, even though two threads incremented it!